# $A_1\subseteq B(\mathscr H_1)$, $A_2\subseteq B(\mathscr H_2)$ are isomorphic $C^*$-algebras. $A_1$ is weakly closed. Is $A_2$ weakly closed?

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras

I guess no?

Let $A$ be commutative and let $B$ be $C(X)\subseteq B(l^2(X))$, where $X$ is compact Hausdorff. Suppose $B$ is weakly closed, take an arbitary $x\in X$, there is a net of operators in $B$ which weakly converges to $1_{\{x\}}$:

$$\mathscr Y=\{Y\subseteq_{finite} X\backslash \{x\}\}\\f_Y(y)=\left\{\begin{array}{}1&,y=x\\0&,y\in Y\\ others&,y\notin Y\cup \{x\}\end{array}\right.$$

Therefore $1_{\{x\}}\in B$. However, $A$ may have no minimal projections.

Is this counter example correct?

But isn't it kind of wired that being isomorphic to a Von Neumann algebra doesn't make itself a Von Neumann algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your counter-example is not correct since your initial assumptions ended up implying that $X$ is discrete
$\big (1_{\{x\}}\in  B\big )$, hence $X$ is finite, so $C(X)$ is a von Neumann algebra, after all.

According to the original definition of von Neumann algebras it doesn't make sense to say that "$M$ is a von Neumann",
rather one would say that "$M$ is von Neumann algebra of operators on  $H$",  where $H$ is a Hilbert space.  In 1956 Sakai found an
intrinsic characterization of von Neumann algebras according to which a C*-algebra $A$ admits a faithful representation
on some Hilbert space $H$ whose range is a weakly closed algebra of operators on $H$ iff $A$ is a dual Banach space.

Sakai's result may then be interpreted as a definition of von Neumann algebras which is representation independent.

I  believe your question can be interpreted as asking whether or not an abstract von Neumann algebra admits a faithful
representation whose range is not a von Neumann algebra.

It is not hard to produce examples of such representations for any given infinite-dimensional von
Neumann
algebra $M$.  All you have to do is choose a non-normal state and consider the corresponding  GNS representation,   adding
to it a copy of
any old faithful representation to make the whole thing faithful.  If $\xi $ is the cyclic vector, then the map
$$
  T\in M\mapsto \langle T\xi , \xi \rangle \in \mathbb C
  $$
will fail to be normal, attesting to the fact that $M$ is not a von Neumann in that representation.